# React Native 0.66.5 - Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission for AttributionSource (Android 12)

Tags: react-native, android-bluetooth, android-12

Our app is trying to support Android 12 and 13, however, starting the app causes a crash showed in the picture below:

[The app crash message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjzYc.png)

The Android manifest includes the bluetooth_scan as shown below:

[Android manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69SeF.png)

Asking the user for permission is shown below:

[Implementing the permission in the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNUZv.png)

The react-native version is 0.66.5, and therefore should support the BLUETOOTH_SCAN. The same asking for permission implementation is used for the previous Android versions asking for "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION", "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" and so on.

Hope someone can help solve this problem.

**Solution**

I found that the app's class controlling the Bluetooth connection/scan already started before asking for the permissions. Permission was not yet granted to use Bluetooth therefore the App crashed.

For people with the same problems. Check if your Bluetooth is turned on before asking for the permissions.

Hope this helps :)